# Pubnub - removing a lot of channels from a lot of channel groups

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I'm using a pattern where each user has his own channel group and when he connects to some chat - chat is added to his group on the backend. This approach allows user to be connected to a lot of channels simultaneously.
Also I have a scheduler that once in a while make a batch remove of DB items to which chatrooms are connected, so I need to remove related channels from user's channel groups.

Questions are:

1. Do I need to do it in order to prevent groups hitting 2k limit? Or inactive channels will be destroyed automatically?
2. Channel Group Maintenance - If i have 2000 chatrooms, ~50 users in each:

   a. how can I effectively clean up user's channel groups?

   b. Can i somehow destroy channel or extract it from all of the groups at once, so i will need to make 2000 calls, or do i need to remove channel per user's channel group and so i will have to make 100 000 calls to `pubnub` at once?

Comment: Just curious, is this with Redis?

Comment: @NiCkNewman nope, main DB is Neo4j.

Comment: @Craig im sorry but i did not quite understood reason for last edit. Whats wrong with FUD and can i have any clarifications regardig removed concerns itself?

Comment: No worries. Your wording was a little *rough* I though but no worries. I think my newly formatted answer covers all your questions more completely and accurately. Especially the part where db updates trigger channel group maintenance. Let me know if you still have further questions. Cheers

Comment: @CraigConover oh, i see, well, pardon me for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Channel Groups

### Channel Group Maintenance

- You need to keep track of the number of channels in a channel group. You can get a list of channels in a channel groups using *list channels* API and then do a count/size on the returned array.
- Channels are not removed from channel groups until your code removes them either one at a time or when the client (that is subscribed to the channel group) invokes the *remove group* API. Just to reemphasize, you would need to do this from the client side, not the server side.
- *Cleaning up* channel groups is just a requirement you implement in your application code, not something that PubNub SDK or server automates. If a user should be removed from a chat room, then remove that channel from that user's channel group.
- Each channel must be removed from each channel group one by one.
- From the server side, invoke *remove channel from channel group* for each channel group it is in. This won't take very long, even if it is 10K's of channel groups.
- It is not recommended to grant the `manage` permission to a client because that holder of the `manage` permission can add any channel they want to a channel group they have `read` permission on and start receiving messages on that channel.

> Proper functioning of channel groups is a mission critical...

Channel Groups work as designed and expected. There is nothing you can not do with respect to maintaining the channels that are in a channel group based on the above guidance provided. PubNub is not going to automate the channels in the channel groups.  I would suggest that you provide some signaling based on database updates so that you can keep your clients' channels groups *clean*. In your app server layer (not in your database layer), you can invoke code from the successful database commit for updates, inserts and deletes that will keep your channel groups properly *groomed* in **realtime** :)

### Signaling Offline Users

When you send a *signal* or any type of message and a subscribing client happens to be offline, your client code can handle this by getting missed messages when the user comes back online. Just enable [Storage & Playback add-on](https://www.pubnub.com/products/storage-and-playback/) and use the `history` API to get the messages since the last time the user was online for all channels.

Comment: I even opened up calculator to ensure haha, 50 * 2000 is 100k. I dont think that i can remove group. Gorup is assigned to a user. I.e each user have own group to which all his chats are connected (on pubnub side). Chat is stored in DB and i know which users are members. So on chat removal i need to remove channel of this chat from groups of all members (one personal group per member).

signalling is not an option here as users may be (and will be) offline at time of this clean up.

Comment: Also, that pretty much a mission critical thing, so is there any means to check groups for leaking, i.e maybe my app does not cleans something, can i check groups status directly from pubnub? What will happend if 2000 limit is reached and i will attempt to add another channel to a group?

Comment: Max - haha not sure what I was thinking - and I'm a math major :) Anyway, the remove group would be client side, not server side (added that to the answer). I also updated the signaling offline issue. I'll get back you on going over 2000 limit. But what do you mean by *status*? Number of channels?

Comment: yep, exacty, i meant number of channels, or maybe even list of exact channels

Comment: regarding offline signaling, yep good point, it can be implemented this way. But then il have to move group management (i.e grant permission for that, at least in this case) on to user's frontend instead of backend (as it is now). Initially by moving group management to backend i was ensuring that users cant get access to channels that they are not allowed to. But if user will have an ability to manage own group, knowing id of some private chat he can add it to own group which is no good. Or i can somehow grant user rights to only remove channels from own group?

Comment: Oh wait, im granting permission to manage channels, not channel groups, so with this approach when user joins chat channel i supposed to give him manage permission over this channel, and then he will be able to get rid of it when time comes. Sounds correct, or am i missing something?

Comment: So please clarify one more thing for me, what access right should have user to add/delete channels to his personal group?"manage" on channel AND "manage" on group? And then he will not be able to add channel that he is not meant to add (i.e have no "manage" over channel but has a "manage" over own group)?

Comment: The `manage` permission is for Channel Groups only, not channels and it allows to adding/removing channels to/from channel groups, but only the channel groups they have the been granted manage on. So grant `manage` to the auth-key for a specific user's channel group and that user (auth-key holder) can only add/remove channels for the channel group.

Comment: And also regarding handling of offline users, can you give me a clue how can i track whot "jobs" from history was completed by user? Posting status messages to the same or side channels upon completion and then comparing them, or there is a way to mark messages in history?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102275/discussion-between-max-yari-and-craig-conover).

Comment: Hello @Craig, i have updated my question with my main concerns left unanswered, can you please reply to that?

Comment: Thanks for new udates, groups are already cleaned up on app level, it's just the fact that i have no way to actually check group's health directly from pubnub. I can make a mistake, as everyone can, and by checking groups channels directly from pubnub i can figure out that i indeed made a mistake somewhere and something is leaking. Now i just need to beleive.
I think that a pretty reasonable feature to have in pubnub, and shouldnt be hard to implement, as there is already some channel tracking on pubnub side, obviously.

Comment: Anyway i gone for just cleaning up on server side in this bulk update case,  hope it will work fine when amount of cleanup will become noticable. Thanks for support!

Comment: Just noticed: In your answer "Just to reemphasize, you would need to do this from the client side, not the server side.". But this will require granting manage permission to user on his channel group, thats the whole point of my concern. Or am i misnderstanding something? If not it just looks a bit controversial in answer to emphasize this and then point out that its not suggested.